# Make barchat x axis value as a range

Tags: reactjs, charts, react-redux, chart.js, chart.js2

So what i am expecting is to make the X axis a range.
as you can see in the picture. I want the first value to start from below the zero and the first bar should be a range like Rp. 6000.00 - Rp. 6820.00.
I am using chart js 2 for this.

Settings:

```
{
  scales: {
    xAxes: [
      {
        categoryPercentage: 1.0,
        barPercentage: 1.0,
        gridLines: {display:false},
        ticks: { }
      }
    ],
    yAxes: [
    {gridLines: {display:false}}
    ]
  },
  legend: { display: false }
}
```

I want the chart to work as a histogram where the bars are range like the X axis numbers should start from the start of each bar[image]

Comment: Sorry, obviously I'm too dumb to understand your question. Am I right that you want to have an offset of the tick labels so they are not in the middle of the bars? They should be between two bars?

Comment: @HeadhunterKev i am sorry my explanation is very dumb.
So i want to have a range. if you see the X axis i want the labels to start from left side of each bar.

Comment: no, as I said, it's my fault. I only know `ticks: { labelOffset: i }` [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration) with `i` as the offset in pixels. Your labels should have a similar length because you can only use pixels. There may be a ticks-callback-option where you can set the position with the coordinates of the bars but this is quite difficult.